# azure pricing for VMs

Tags: azure

I would like to know if azure charges will only apply for the resources that I have used regardless if I hosted have multiple sites inside my azure VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to be alittle more specific.

Typically the cloud providers charge for the time you allocate resources even if you dont use them.

Let's say you host 100 sites in one allocated instance you will only be charge for one instance.

If you host 0 sites you will still be charged for one instance.